# Extracting strings that contains particular words

Tags: java, regex

This code can extract sentences that contain a particular word. The problem is if I want to extract several sentences based on different words I must copy it several times. Is there a way of doing this with several words? possibly feeding an array to it?

```
String o = "Trying to extract this string. And also the one next to it.";       
String[] sent = o.split("\\.");
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String sentence : sent) {
    if (sentence.contains("this")) {
        output.add(sentence);
    }
}       
System.out.println(">>output=" + output);
```

Comment: Your code has several issues. The method `substring` appears twice and is nested. Please try to fix that. Also, `wow` is not known in that context. I'm sorry but I don't get what you are trying to do... you have a string `"have"` which you split by spaces which gives you `{ "have" }` and you are not using the array in the end

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted code I'd been messing around with...

Comment: So your question is if you can have multiple words and if one of that word exists in the sentence the sentence should be extracted?

Comment: Thank you very much these are all amazing solutions that I hope help people in similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String o = "Trying to extract this string. And also the one next to it.";
String[] sent = o.split("\\.");
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
keyList.add("this");
keyList.add("these");
keyList.add("that");

List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String sentence : sent) {
    for (String key : keyList) {
        if (sentence.contains(key)) {
            output.add(sentence);
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(">>output=" + output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sentence = "First String. Second Int. Third String. Fourth Array. Fifth Double. Sixth Boolean. Seventh String";
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String each: sentence.split("\\.")){
    if(inKeyword(each)) output.add(each);
}

System.out.println(output);
```

Helper Function:

```
public static Boolean inKeyword(String currentSentence){
    String[] keyword = {"int", "double"};

    for(String each: keyword){
        if(currentSentence.toLowerCase().contains(each)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of words to filter for called `filter` and an array of sentences you could use [`Collections.disjoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)) to compare if the words of that sentence does not overlap with the words to filter for. Sadly, this does not work if you filter for `"However"` and your sentence contains `"However,"`.

```
Collection<String> filter = /**/;
String[] sentences = /**/;
List<String> result = new ArrayList();
for(String sentence : sentences) {
    Collection<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));
    // If they do not not overlap, they overlap
    if (!Collections.disjoint(words, filter)) {
        result.add(sentence);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With streams (splitting into sentences and words):

```
    String o = "Trying to extract this string. And also the one next to it.";
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("this", "also"));

    List<String> output = Arrays.stream(o.split("\\.")).filter(
            sentence -> Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s")).anyMatch(
                    word -> words.contains(word)
            )
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(">>output=" + output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.matches` as follows.

```
String sentence = ...;
if (sentence.matches(".*(you|can|use).*")) { // Or:
if (sentence.matches(".*\\b(you|can|use)\\b.*")) { // With word boundaries

if (sentence.matches("(?i).*(you|can|use).*")) { // Case insensitive ("You")
```

In java 8 the following variations might do:

```
String pattern = ".*(you|can|use).*";

String pattern = new StringJoiner("|", ".*(", ").*)
    .add("you")
    .add("can")
    .add("use")
    .toString();
// Or a stream on the words with a joining collector

Arrays.stream(o.split("\\.\\s*"))
    filter(sentence -> sentence.matches(pattern))
    forEach(System.out::println);
```